# How do I store a current bead color to a local variable when clicked on?

Tags: javascript

I'm using perlenspiel with a sublime text editor and part of my assignment is making a grid with multi-colored boxes using loops. I've got all the boxes and the colors down, but now I have to get the current color of a bead when clicked on, and store it to a local variable. How do I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you just asked, you're going to have to be a lot more specific if you expect people to help you. Please improve your question.

Comment: For a programming class, I'm using perlenspiel and a sublimetext editor to program stuff into google html using javascript.

I've been using for (var) loops in order to color boxes in a 16 x 16 grid, but now I have to make it so that when I click on a bead within the grid, the current color shows up, and the x and y values of that color are printed in the debug. How do I do that?

Comment: @user3732264: You shouldn't assume people will know what "perlenspiel" is. When talking about less common APIs, providing a link is quite helpful, and also tagging appropriately.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is homework and cites no previous coding attempt

Answer (score 0):

http://users.wpi.edu/~bmoriarty/ps2/beads.html#beadcolor :

> PS.BeadColor() lets you change **and/or check** the color of beads.

(emphasis mine). Just don't specify the new colour, you only give `x` and `y`, that you get from `PS.Click()`.

EDIT: sorry, wrong version. I suppose this is better:

http://users.wpi.edu/~bmoriarty/ps/beads.html#color :

> PS.color() returns a RGB multiplex integer indicating the current color of the bead.

```
PS.touch = function(x, y, data, options) {
   "use strict";

   var color = PS.color(x, y);
   // and then, something happens. Brilliant, eh?
};
```

Comment: I have to use PS.color and if I put in just PS.color(x, y); in the ps.touch area, it does nothing

Comment: Of course. It reads the colour. You have to do something with it to be useful. It's like if you say "I'm hungry"; someone gives you an apple; and you say "Thanks, but I'm still hungry :(" while holding the apple in your hand. Do something with it. :)

Comment: So far, I have just:

var oldColor = PS.color(x, y);
PS.debug(oldColor + "\n");

All this does is list the color number when a bead is clicked on. What do I do in order to have the x and y value print out along with the color? Sorry if these are noobish questions, it's my first time programming ever in this class.